# How to use Promise.all() with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is what I want to do:

```
Promise.all([aurelia.start(), entityManagerProvider.initialize()])
    .then((results:Array<any>) => {
        let aurelia: any = results[0];
        aurelia.setRoot();
    });
```

`aurelia.start()` returns an Aurelia type, while `initialize()` returns void.

The compiler gives an error message that the type cannot be inferred from the usage.

What I am trying to achieve is to get them to run at the same time, as they are both very long processes, then run `Aurelia.setRoot();`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Its generally best to have arrays with consistent types. You can do the following manually though (passing in generic arguments):

```
Promise.all<Aurelia, void>(
  [aurelia.start(), entityManagerProvider.initialize()
])
.then(results => {
    let aurelia = results[0];
    aurelia.setRoot();
});
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code approves that syntax but the ```tslint``` bundled in my build system complains: ```the array is not declared correctly it should be Type[] or Array<Type>```. Strangely, searching for that error message yields exactly **0** results.

Comment: so write `let foo : Array<Promise<Aurelia>,Promise<void>> = [aurelia.start(), entityManagerProvider.initialize()];`

Comment: Looks like this is working for me with pure inference now.  It returns a type of Promise<[T1,T2]> which works great.  I'm not sure if this is due to recent compiler features or just that the typings for ES6 promises are now better than they used to be.  At any rate, the inference here is impressive.

Comment: -1: Typing via `Promise.all<T, Y, Z, number, ...>` is more straightforward than declaring a typed array of promises first. See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430386/457268

Answer (score 69):

Since `Promise::all` is a generic function, you can declare the return types of each promise like this:

```
Promise.all<Aurelia, void>([
  aurelia.start(),
  entityManagerProvider.initialize()
])
.then(([aurelia]) => aurelia.setRoot());
```

Comment: in vscode it works perfectly. but somehow when i compile it via tsc it says `error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` (tsc -v 2.0.6). Any solutions?

Comment: This yields *"Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."* in 2.1.4 as well.

Comment: In Typescript `2.7.2`, I'm finding that it is able to correctly infer the types in the array passed into the `then()` block without even having to declare the types 'ahead of time' as generic parameters upon `Promise::all`.

Comment: @JamieBirch thanks, it seems to work on `2.7.1` as well.

Answer (score 30):

At least from TypeScript `2.7.1` onwards, the compiler seems to resolve the types without help, with a syntax like this:

```
Promise.all([fooPromise, barPromise]).then(([foo, bar]) => {
  // compiler correctly warns if someField not found from foo's type
  console.log(foo.someField);
});
```

Hat tip: @JamieBirch (from comment to @AndrewKirkegaard's answer)

Comment: Or better yet `const results: [foo, bar] = await Promise.all([fooPromise, barPromise]);` to update this slightly

Answer (score 11):

If you'd like to keep type-safety, it's possible to **extend the native type-definition** of the `Promise` object (of type `PromiseConstructor`) with additional overload signatures for when `Promise.all` is called with a finite number of not-necessarily inter-assignable values:

```
interface PromiseConstructor
{
    all<T1, T2>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
    all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [T1 | PromiseLike<T1>, T2 | PromiseLike<T2>, T3 | PromiseLike<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
    ...
}
```

Add as many overloads as you need. This approach provides full type-safety for all elements in the `value` argument of the `onfulfilled` callback:

```
Promise.all([1, "string", true]).then(value =>
{
    let a: number = value[0]; // OK
    let b: number = value[1]; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    ...
});
```

Comment: I think that is an elegant solution.

Comment: Doesn't scale very well when you don't know how many you will have in advance

Comment: @blockhead If you need more than about 3-5 you are better off restructuring to receive a single object anyways. This is precisely for the cases where you only have _some_ values to consider.

Answer (score 3):

### PART 1

There are functions you need to understand A) `Promise.all` and B) `Promise.then`:

A) the type definition of `Promise.all` is a function:

```
    all<T>(values: readonly (T | PromiseLike<T>)[]): Promise<T[]>;
```

B) the type definition of `Promise.then` is a function that is a bit more complex:

```
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
```

#### PART 1.a

`Promise.then`'s type definition is a lot but it can be broken down into small parts:

`then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>` a function `then` with 2 generics `TResult1, TResult2`. The `< >` means we can set and use values inside them later - they are called [generics](https://medium.com/@lightworld/example-42-typescript-generics-9fdd124f9f49).

The `then` function itself: `(onfulfilled?: ..., onrejected?: ...): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>`.

`PromiseLike` is a helper type and the same as `Promise` (for an intro lesson).

`onfulfiled` and `onrejected` are functions in the form of: `(value: T) => (TResult1 OR PromiseLike<TResult1>)` OR `undefined` OR `null`. Notice the generic `T` is used here.

### PART 2 -

Promise itself has a generic interface: `interface Promise<T>`. The `<T>` is a/the [generic](https://medium.com/@lightworld/example-42-typescript-generics-9fdd124f9f49).

So when you call

```
Promise.all<SomeCoolType>([a(), b(), c()]).then( value => doSomething(value) )
```

your generic is `SomeCoolType` and in this example some cool type is

`interface SomeCoolType = [A() => string, B() => boolean, C() => number]`

Now remember that `A B C` have to be Promises. And this makes it so your `value` in `.then( value => ...` is going to the result of `SomeCoolType` which for us is calling all those functions, the result is `[string, boolean, number]`.

### CONCLUSION -

Concretely, the array of function/promises you pass into you `Promise.all<T>` are generics that are used in `.then(result => ...)`. The return/resolve value of those promises will become the value/type of `result`.

Example: `Promise.all<[Promise<() => string>]>([returnStringAsync()]).then(result => console.log(typeof result === "string")); # => true`

Answer (score 3):

A full example:

```js
type returnString = string;
type returnNumberType = number;
type jobsType = [Promise<returnString>, Promise<returnNumberType>];

const returnString = async (): Promise<returnString> => {
  return 'This is a string';
};

const returnNumber = async (): Promise<returnNumberType> => {
  return 123;
};

const jobs = [];

jobs.push(returnString());

if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  jobs.push(returnNumber());
}

(async () => {
  const results = await Promise.all(jobs as jobsType);
  // results now has the correct.
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
  console.log(results);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a way to use Promise.all in React **TypeScript**:

```
Promise.all<Foo, Bar>(fooPromise, barPromise)
```

where `fooPromise` and `barPromise` are the promises you want to execute in parallel, `fooPromise` returns a `foo` type response, and `barPromise` returns a `bar` type response.

If you check the response at `.then`, you'll see the response is a tuple: `[Foo, Bar]`.

Answer (score 1):

When using promises that return values, my favorite using of `Promise.all()` is using array destructuring as below. Using `await` is more readable and destructuring is filling up the right variables.

```
export interface IDeveVersionHubDataService {
    getBuildFilterDeveVersions(): Promise<IBuildFilterDeveVersionDto[]>;
    getBuildFilterUsers(): Promise<IBuildFilterUserDto[]>;
}
```

```
const loadDeveVersions = deveVersionHubDataService.getBuildFilterDeveVersions();
const loadUsers = deveVersionHubDataService.getBuildFilterUsers();

const [deveVersions, users] = await Promise.all([loadDeveVersions, loadUsers]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow landed here when I was looking for return type of `Promise.all()` since straightforward `[Promise<any>, Promise<any>]` is obviously not working.

Eventually it turned out to be simplier than it seems:

```
const severalMongoDbOperations: Promise<[DeleteWriteOpResultObject, UpdateWriteOpResult]> =
  () => Promise.all([
    mongo.deleteOne({ ... }),
    mongo.updateOne({ ... })
  ]);
```

Later it can be used with `.then()` or:

```
try {
  const ops: [DeleteWriteOpResultObject, UpdateWriteOpResult] = await severalMongoDbOperations();
} catch (e) {
  // Process rejection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you, but with this code, all work perfectly.

```
type TList = Promise<Aurelia> | Promise<void>;

const foo: TList[] = [aurelia.start(), entityManagerProvider.initialize()];

Promise.all<TList>(foo).then((results) => {
    let aurelia = results[0];
    aurelia.setRoot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all returns "a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises" (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)).

You can get the results of all the promises if you await the promise all.

```
        const [tomorrow, today, yesterday] = await Promise.all([
            fun('tomorrow'),
            fun('today'),
            fun('yesterday')
        ]);
```

Comment: No: `Promise.all` returns "a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises" (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)). Also, this question was about TypeScript and the type inference with different input promise types.

Comment: @boycy thanks for pointing out the error in my wording. I changed my post.

Answer (score 0):

In this example OrderHistoryParser.parseOrders() returns Order[] type and StorageUtils.getLocalProperty generic:

```
return Promise.all([OrderHistoryParser.parseOrders(), StorageUtils.getLocalProperty(StorageProperties.SESSION_PARSE_RESULT) as Promise<ParseResults>])
      .then(([parsedOrders, sessionParsedResult]) => {
        here 
        parsedOrders would be Order[]
        sessionParsedResult would be ParseResults

      })
```