# Typescript typings for Promise.all working with object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

There is a counterpart for `Promise.all` waiting for all promises in object. Sample implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-all

Usage:

```
await promiseAll({ 
    key1: Promise.resolve(1), 
    key2: Promise.resolve(2) 
});
```

I wanted to write typings for such function. I tried using `keyof` but after a while, I noticed that I would somehow need to "unwrap" a type of a Promise which I doubt is possible.

Here's what I came with which is actually just an identity mapping now :D

```
function promiseAll(o: object): { [P in keyof typeof o]: typeof o[P] } {
...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Promise.All with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684634/how-to-use-promise-all-with-typescript)

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate @DerekBrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, I figured it out!

```
type Promised<T> = { [P in keyof T]: PromiseLike<T[P]> };
function promiseAll<T>(o: Promised<T>): T {
  ...
}
```