# One promise with undefined as return type infects other promises in Promise.all with undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, async-await

I have a few await functions:

```
public async func1(): Promise<ResultType1>();
public async func2(): Promise<ResultType2>();
```

One of them can return `undefined`:

```
public async func3(): Promise<ResultType3|undefined>();
```

(All code is simplified and all my production defails are removed for readability).

When I use `Promise.all` on first two functions, all is good:

```
const resultAll = await Promise.all([func1(), func2()];
// resultAll: [ResultType1, ResultType2]
```

But when I include `func3` in the array of promises to wait on, suddenly ALL return values can be `undefined`:

```
const resultAll2 = await Promise.all([func1(), func2(), func3()]);
// resultAll: [ResultType1 | undefined, ResultType2 | undefined, ResultType3 | undefined]
```

But I want to get value of type `[ResultType1, ResultType2, ResultType3 | undefined]`.

Why does it happen, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: If anyone could suggest a more informative title for this question, it would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430386/312725), I was able to fix it by declaring types explicitly:

```
const resultAllExplicit = await Promise.all<ResultType1, ResultType2, ResultTyp3 | undefined>([func1(), func2(), func3()]);
```

Still curious as to what's the reason for this.