# Can't call array methods on void after using Promise.all to return an array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

For reference: [How to use Promise.all() with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684634/how-to-use-promise-all-with-typescript)

I have a TypeScript application that I want to use Promise.all() in.

I create an array of promises, call Promise.all on the array, and then use .then to map an array of the responses.

Later in the application, I call .map again on the array of responses, but TypeScript complains that "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void | any[]'". (In my actual application, I am calling .filter, but the problem applies to all array methods).

I just can't seem to get around the fact that, for TypeScript, my Promise.all might return void rather than an array of any[].

Here's an example that makes three requests using Axios:

```
const requests = [1, 2, 3].map((request) =>
 axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/test${request}`)
);

const promises = await Promise.all(requests)
  .then((responses) => responses.map((response) => response.data))
  .catch(({ message }) => console.log(message));

// later on...

const responses = promises.map(promise => promise.hello);
```

It's this last line that causes the error "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void | any[]'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)".

How can I tell the compiler that my Promise.all is going to result in an array?

Comment: If the `catch()` call triggers then `promises` will be of type `void`, right?  So you should check `promises` for truthiness before using it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/aNndxW) maybe.  Does that work for you or do you need something else?

Comment: yes @jcalz, thank you, it was the .catch() causing the issue here

Answer (score 0):

As helpfully pointed out by @jcalz, the issue here is the .catch which will return a type of void.

Checking for the existence of the promises array causes the compiler error to go away:

```
let responses;
if(promises) {
  responses = promises.map(response => response.hello);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to rather remove the `.catch()`. You probably don't want to deal with errors by logging them and just returning `undefined`. Instead, let the exception propagate and have the caller of your function actually *handle* it.