# How to assign multiple data type to one variable in typescript + angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a scenario where under `promiseAll`, I am sending two requests and in `then` block combine response returns so I need to define two datatype. I defined like this way

```
Promise.all<FirstType[], SecondType>([this.firstAPIHit, this.secondAPIHit(Id)]).then((data: [FirstType[], SecondType]): void => {
```

`FirstType` is `Array List` **Ex: [{Id: 1, Name: "Test"}, {Id: 2, Name: "Random"}]**

`SecondType` is `object` **Ex: {Id: "12345", city: null, location: Array(1)}**

As a functionality it is working perfectly fine with error till Angular 8 but I just recently migrated it to Angular 11 and it start throwing an error

```
 0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

After debugging I find if I remove this type declaration then error removed immediately. But I do not suppose to remove it.

Any help in same context where I can assign both to same variable?

Response contains `data---> (2) [Array(3), {…}]`

---

New Edit :

I find same error at other places too and I find where I defined like below are showing error now:

```
abc: [number, string][]

private myFunction(chart): [IChartData[], number, number] {...}
```

May it will help someone to answer my query!

Comment: No. it is not. It is actually not related to `map` operator. It's something like type issue which typescript is not able to resolve it.

Comment: this is the way code is written 

`Promise.all<FirstType[], SecondType>([this.firstAPIHit, this.secondAPIHit(Id)]).then((data: [FirstType[], SecondType]): void => {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684634/how-to-use-promise-all-with-typescript check this out. may be helpful

Comment: Use `any` data type in `Promise.all` and then determine that the value is array or not with `Array.isArray(value)`. If the result is `true` use `value as []` to use `map method

Comment: Currently I am not using `map` anywhere in the file or flow and I can't use `any` datatype. That is not a solution!

Comment: @AmbujKhanna Are you sure `this.firstAPIHit` returns array of `FirstType[]` ?

Comment: Yes. There is no break in the functionality. This is just a lint issue and which affected in Typescript v4.0. I just verified it is passing in Typescript v3.9

Comment: @GaurangDhorda You have removed type of response where I have issue. I can't remove type of response. I have to keep it or define in difference manner!

Comment: @AmbujKhanna Here is updated link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzyn1n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts